# Tfjs-tflite load custom converted model, dlopen error

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js, emscripten, dlopen

tflite models from tensorflowhub are loadable,
but custom converted keras -> tflite model results in error:

```
RuntimeError: abort(To use dlopen, you need to use Emscripten's linking support, see https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/wiki/Linking).
Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.
```